# Recommended site for Java programming focused on web mapping

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am trying to start learning coding in [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), but as a [GIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) specialist, I would like to start coding in Java for Web mapping application.

I don't know what is a good package to start coding for mapping purposes with the main focus on the web. Can you recommended a site for Java programming focused on web mapping?

Comment: Programming related to web mapping is certainly on-topic at [gis.se] but it sounds like you may be seeking [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: I already have an account there but i was looking for a discussion topic, and i couldn't post it at gis.stack, i thought that i could post it here.

Comment: Discussion is fine in the GIS Chat Room but not in its Main site.

Answer (score 2):

There is no site on the SE network that suits this type of questions.

You have a site for [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com) and a site for programming: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), but none of these sites are there for you to start learning how to program. You can search for tutorials online. Here is not the place to ask for them.

If you have a specific programming question, feel free to ask on Stack Overflow. We are glad to help you on that.